# Selenium browsing with headless isn't working?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox-headless

I'm trying to use Selenium with a headless browser but when I run this code below it still opens the browser?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def address_One():
    page_Number = 1
    while page_Number <= 15:
        with open("/home/admin-acc/Desktop/user-information.txt", mode="a") as writer:
            url = f"https://advanced.name/freeproxy?page={page_Number}"
            options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
            options.add_argument("--headless")
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
            driver.get(url)
            all_ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-ip]')
            all_ports = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-port]')
        for ip, port in zip(all_ips, all_ports):
            print(ip.text, port.text)
        driver.quit()
        page_Number += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    address_One()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the below **changes** and it seems to be working fine :

**Explanation** : Instantiate the driver in IF clause, then pass it to the `address_One` like below :

```
def address_One(driver):
    page_Number = 1
    while page_Number <= 15:
        with open("/home/admin-acc/Desktop/user-information.txt", mode="a") as writer:
            url = f"https://advanced.name/freeproxy?page={page_Number}"
            driver.get(url)
            all_ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-ip]')
            all_ports = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@data-port]')
        for ip, port in zip(all_ips, all_ports):
            print(ip.text, port.text)
        driver.quit()
        page_Number += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executablePath = r'C:\geckodriver.exe'
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = executablePath, options=options)
    address_One(driver)
```

**Output :**

```
91.137.238.54 8082
190.83.125.15 999
143.255.52.102 31158
41.180.68.195 8080
187.60.121.246 3128
138.122.99.102 999
200.199.143.162 8080
45.5.117.250 999
129.205.127.30 8080
177.47.181.250 8080
190.131.229.133 999
45.160.78.5 999
190.121.13.140 999
103.52.211.126 80
143.55.57.18 8080
116.90.229.186 35561
45.189.252.42 999
45.235.216.112 8080
103.137.199.129 8080
103.103.212.222 53281
40.73.42.49 3128
170.231.187.209 8080
187.92.132.14 8080
27.123.1.46 3128
36.89.51.165 8080
102.164.248.157 8080
45.234.16.194 8080
103.243.82.198 37358
8.210.88.234 3128
49.0.41.81 38235
103.101.233.13 8080
103.94.164.16 8088
103.154.65.218 8080
202.152.12.202 8080
45.236.103.33 8085
190.52.198.180 8080
178.32.129.31 3128
110.78.81.107 8080
45.236.103.130 8085
103.122.64.212 8080
103.52.211.138 80
170.83.79.105 999
104.238.195.10 80
177.70.243.41 8080
176.32.185.22 8080
190.83.125.17 999
177.92.0.2 8080
89.20.48.118 8080
52.151.15.4 80
45.251.231.78 8080
103.110.10.206 8080
103.198.126.237 8888
59.124.224.180 3128
178.18.255.175 3128
45.234.5.197 6666
45.174.248.4 999
195.154.67.61 3128
51.75.144.32 3128
103.146.151.58 8080
49.75.59.242 3128
190.108.200.176 8080
45.189.252.9 999
183.88.192.112 8080
```

Comment: When I put driver in address_One I get "Unexpected argument ".  Also I get "DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=executablePath, options=options)"  When I run the program, it does run though.  However, after running it it only gets the first page, it will then throw Connection refused?

Comment: Which selenium version are you using ?

Comment: I am using 4.0.0a1

Comment: Also do you know of a way for it to essentially keep the same browser process open, I'm guessing it would be better performance if it wasn't opening a new browser each time?  Even though it's happening in the background?

Comment: yeah that is in beta. can you try with 3.X

Comment: I figured it out.  I am having another issue, how can I send keys to the URL?  For example, I don't want to close and open the browser when I got to the next page, I remember I can type in the URL but can't remember how and can't find the answer online.

Comment: I can not really believe, the same code works just fine on my local. Why do you have to do send keys in URL ? embed them in URL directly ?

Comment: Yeah, that way it's not opening another browser.  I want it to go to the next page in the same browser.

Comment: I believe this is not regarding this ticket right ? Did the above solution work for intended question ?

Comment: fair enough.  I marked yours correct, thank you.

Comment: Please raise a new ticket with the exact issue that you have been facing , that will have a much more visibility than this. Thank you !